# kindle as a server monitoring screen

Tags: monitoring, kindle

I saw someone using a kindle to display server load/stats.

It's all text such as page response time and # of current active users.

How should I go about creating a such display on kindle?

Comment: Kindle uses a flavor of Android (Fire OS) so there is a start..

Comment: Not familiar with kindle, but sounds like 1)fetch data 2)create PDF 3) send it to display

Comment: Ahh, so if it is as @LucasCrawford said, it is even better. For android: 1)Fetch data 2) Send it to display (in some kindle-only way)